# Blender black textures

Tags: textures, blender

I am making a game with GLSL shading in Blender. Some faces have normal textures but others are black. I ve applied many textures to the same objects different faces, but they appear black in viewport and when rendered

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but if you are, then you should try adding lights to your scene that illuminate the object from every angle. If this isn't the answer you're looking for, then I'd suggest going to the mapping submenu under the texture menu, then changing the coordinates and projection to suit your object.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to edit mode.
2. Select all the faces by pressing 'A'
3. Select Mesh>Normals>Recalculate Outside (Ctrl+N works as a shortcut)

Hope this helped....